# Wrong output in my code

Tags: java

I get wrong output when I run this code .. The output should be 
`x is added to the set` but Iam getting output like this :

```
x is added to the set
x is added to the set
x is already added
x is already added
```

My code:

```
List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
data.add(4);
data.add(1);

int x = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    if (data.get(i).equals(x)) {
        System.out.println("x is already added");
    } else {
        data.add(x);
        System.out.println("x is added to the set");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your output is correct, if you expected different output then it is your code which is wrong.

Comment: I want to get output like this : x is added to the set ,, How to do that???

Comment: Yes your output is right.

Comment: I suggest you follow the steps carefully and keep track of the value of `i` and the items in `data`. You should be able to spot the mistake.

Comment: I want to get output like this : x is added to the set ,, How to do that?

Comment: add break just after System.out.println("x is added to the set");

Comment: God bless you all it works after inserting break ..thanks

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and explain in more details what is your code *suppose* to do (what problem you are trying to solve). Then we can try explaining where your mistake is and how to solve it.

Comment: What do you want the output to be if `int x = 1;` (after adding 4 and 1 to the list) ?

Comment: same output as before .. as long the x value is not in the data so I want to add it otherwise if x value is already in data so I want to print "x is already added"

Comment: @java that's what I thought. In that case you need to look at all the elements before adding anything. If the array contains [4, 1] and you're adding 1, it should tell you that it has already been added, correct? The code you currently have will not do that.

Comment: is not my for loop search in data before I add any thing??? how you fix this problem .. I changed int x=5 to int x= 1 and I got "x is added to the set" So how to fix this problem...thanks

Comment: @java If the array is [4, 1] and you're adding 1, your code looks at the first element, sees that it's not 1, and will add 1 to the array. So the new array will be [4, 1, 1]. See Eduardo's answer for detailed steps of what's happening.

Comment: yes brother you are correct ... I did see his answer but how to fix that issue I just do not want to add same number two times .. what is your suggest ..thanks

Comment: @java You need to look at all the elements to see if any of them equals `x`. Only then, after the for loop is over, can you decide whether you should add it or not. Alternatively there's the method `List#contains(Object)` which you could use instead of the for loop.

Comment: God bless you ... I wish you enter heaven brother .. I understand now ..thank you very much :)

Comment: @java You're welcome. See my edited answer for a more standard way of doing this.

Comment: OK brother Cinnam :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `for` loop, you can do this:

```
boolean alreadyAdded = false;

for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    if (data.get(i).equals(x)) {
        alreadyAdded = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!alreadyAdded) {
    data.add(x);
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Since you're using `List`, a better way of doing this would be

```
if (!data.contains(x)) {
    data.add(x);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your array length is 2. So the loop would be run twice (if no other elements were added to the array).

First time data.get(0) is 4, so 5 is added to the set. Now data.length is 3.

```
x is added to the set
```

Second time data.get(1) is 1, so 5 is added to the set. Now data.length is 4.

```
x is added to the set
```

Third time data.get(2) is 5

```
x is already added
```

Fourth time (since data.length is 4), data.get(3) is 5 so you get:

```
x is already added
```

If you really want to exit the loop after adding the 5 to the array, break the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    if (data.get(i).equals(x)) {
        System.out.println("x is already added");
        break;
    } else {
        data.add(x);
        System.out.println("x is added to the set");
    }
}
```

But that logic is very stupid. If you only want to add the five and show the message, whay don't you do it directly without loops or anything else?

Comment: It seems the OP wants to check if the list contains `x` and if not, then add it to the list.

Comment: I changed int x=5 to int x= 1 and I got "x is added to the set" So how to fix this problem... I just do not want to add same number two times in data .. what is your suggest (as you see I have a for loop in my code) ..thanks

Comment: I think you need to learn a bit more about programming. Why don't you use a java.util.List, then use contains() method? If the list contains the number, then not add it else you add it.